# Is there a Native Android Layout Similar to Bootstrap Grid System?

Tags: android, xml, twitter-bootstrap, android-layout

`ConstraintLayout` in Android seems promising, but it doesn't seem to be able to respond to resolution changes caused by orientation change, or having a different layout on tablet. I.e. having 2 cards side-by-side in landscape mode, or the 2 cards above and below each other in portrait mode.

I know we could create multiple layout files depending on the resolution or orientation, but the best part about `Twitter-Bootstrap` is that its grid system allows you to define the way a layout is presented for multiple screen widths all in one HTML file.

Is there a way to achieve this in XML without using any 3rd party extensions or custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is designed to handle different screen orientations and dimensions through the xml files. As far as I know if you don't want to use a third-party or custom code, there is no other way to do it but using the xml files and layouts folders.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. I did see a project on GitHub called flexbox-layout that seems promising if I ever really need this feature.